# How to solve Selenium error message: tried to run command without establishing a connection?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to harvest frequency of text appearance from many pages using Selenium (Python). After 1 hour or so of harvesting, this error keeps showing up:

> Tried to run command without establishing a connection

at this line:

> driver.get(url)

What could be the cause/solution for this? Below is my code, (a function that I repeatedly invoke).

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path = 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/geckodriver')


def get_attack_mention_count(mention,srch_resultsQ):
    #harvesting
    totalQ=0
    for result in srch_resultsQ:
        url=result['link'][2]['@href']
        #page = requests.get(url)

        driver.get(url)##################ERROR HERE ##########################################
        print("URL:",url)
        time.sleep(3)
        delay = 20 # seconds
        try:
            myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'Highlight-module__1p2SO')))
            print ("Page is ready!")
        except TimeoutException:
            print ("Loading took too much time!")
        except:
            print ("exception raised")
            continue
        text_elements =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Highlight-module__1p2SO");
        for element in text_elements:
            element_text=element.text
            count = sum(element_text.replace("-"," ").upper().count(x.upper().replace("-"," ")) for x in mention)
            print("count:",count)
            totalQ+=count
        print("end of paper...total so far for ",mention,": ",totalQ)
        #driver.close()
        #sys.exit()
    print ("total occurances= ",totalQ)
    return totalQ
```

Comment: Sounds like the browser isn't launching.  Check your path... seems like those should be backslashes... and be sure to check Python docs in regards to escaping.

Comment: @pcalkins It's launching since it runs and harvest for 1 hour and sometimes more. The error shows up suddenly after many successful launches/harvesting.

Comment: possibly a hung/orphaned driver... (that can happen for many different reasons)  What helps with that is to make sure there's some pause between quitting one driver and launching another.  (Try/catch your driver initialization and quit() calls to check for exceptions when launching/quitting the driver...)

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens due to use of `driver.close()` frequently

Comment: Do you have any solution to propose to the author?